# If $a^2+b^2=c^2$ then $a$ or $b$ is even.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am having trouble proving this directly. I know that it is easy to prove by contradiction by assuming both $a$ and $b$ to be odd, but how should I start to try to prove this? This is a homework problem and I am just looking for help getting started, not the full answer.

Comment: Try looking at it mod $4$ and consider what $a^2$ and $b^2$ and $c^2$ can be mod $4$.

Comment: That"s an indirect proof. @MiloBrandt

Comment: I think this question could be improved by mentioning what is meant by *indirect*. All answers until now come down to the same thing, that what @MiloBrandt said, and that is appearantly not direct enough.

Comment: If you can prove it by contradiction, that is $X \vdash Y \vdash Z \vdash \text{false}$, then just convert it to a direct proof as $\text{true} \vdash \lnot Z \vdash \lnot Y \vdash \lnot X$.  If you need help with that, edit your question to contain your proof by contradiction, and ping me here, and I'll add an answer showing you how to convert it to a direct proof.  Actually I think it might not be so easy to prove by contradiction as you have heard.

Comment: What's the value / worth of a 'direct' proof ?

Comment: @dohmatob The value might be as simple as it being a homework problem. Or one might prefer direct proofs because they are more constructive in nature.

Comment: I agree that most *intuitionists* would rather accept a *direct* proof, as it usually comes with some amount of *constructive* exhibition. Also, what is *direct* or *indirect* is really a matter of convenience (for example a professor testing whether pupils have mastered a particular concept, as it appears to be the case here, etc.). Finally, the tricky proposal of @DanielV shows, once again, how slippery the notion of *direct* / *indirect* proof is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: every odd perfect square is of the form $4m+1$.

Comment: That outlines an indirect proof, not a direct proof.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: In my opinion, ajotatxe's proof is a good as you can get. Any 'direct' proof will somehow have to grind through a mechanical version of his one-sentence proof!

Comment: Well, if he is going to post an indirect proof when the question specifically say "I know the indirect proof," the very least he can do is note the lack of an answer in the answer. @dohmatob

Comment: "..lack of an answer in the answer" ? Am I the only person who thinks this is senselessly rude ? You can't bash down some good mathematics just to win a few points on SE.

Comment: @dohmatob I dislike answers that ignore the question, not for points. I have more than enough points. I criticized this answer before I came up with my answer. Maybe you should think a little about your level of rudeness, first, before lecturing people. This does not answer the question, nor does it indicate in any way that the answered has read the title of the question.

Comment: Well, of course it does answer the question :)

Comment: No it does not, because the question is "prove directly." And, as your answer shows, this hint only lets you prove it indirectly. @dohmatob

Answer (score 2):

We will assume two lemmas:

1. For all integers $d$, $d^2-d$ is even.
2. For integers $a,b$, if $ab$ is even, then one of $a,b$ is even.

We can deduce from lemma 1 and that $a^2+b^2=c^2$ that $a+b\equiv c\pmod {2}$. Since $c\equiv -c\pmod{2}$, we have that $a+b\equiv -c\pmod{2}$. This means that $$4\mid (a+b-c)(a+b+c)=(a+b)^2-c^2 = a^2+b^2-c^2 + 2ab=2ab$$

Since $4\mid 2ab$, you have that $2\mid ab$. So one of $a,b$ must be even by Lemma 2.

Lemma 1 can be proven by induction.

I think we are hiding the indirect part of the proof in Lemma 2. It is how the rest of the proof avoids proving an "or" statement, and avoids breaking it up into cases - by treating "$a$ is even or $b$ is even" as implied by "$ab$ is even."

Comment: Hum ... This is just as 'indirect' as @ajotatxe's. Except that this one is much more mechanical.

Comment: At this point, I wonder if you really know what an indirect proof is, @dohmatob this is a direct proof that $ab$ is even. Whether that is sufficient to satisfy OPs condition I explicitly leave to others to judge, clearly indicating that I have read the question.

Comment: yes, I know what a direct proof is. I can also identify childish and rude high-school behavior, indicative of immaturity in the trade...

Comment: just a troll, then. Never mind. No apologies for you false accusation that I was grubbing for points? of course not, you ar a fine person to be lecturing me. I honestly thought, not knowing you, that maybe you didn't know what an indirect proof was. Often, on this site, the problem is differences in language, for example. Bu keep the insults flowing, they'll suit you in he long run, @dohmatob

Comment: Sorry if these came across as insults. It wasn't my intention.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a fine line between proving directly and by contradiction. Try breaking it into cases, such as

Suppose $c^2$ is even/odd and WLOG $b$ is odd, then show that $a$ must be even.

Since the conclusion isn't a contradiction, but rather that $a$ is even, this is a direct proof. You should end with something like $a = 2*n$ where $n$ is an integer (definition of even).

It might help if you have a theorem that says that $a$ and $a^2$ have the same parity. Maybe worth a lemma.

Answer (score 1):

## Unrolling @ajotatxe's one-sentence proof

**Auxiliary claim:** Every odd perfect square is of the form $4m + 1$.

*Proof.* $(2k + 1)^2 = 4(k^2 + k) + 1 = 1 (\text{ mod } 4)$. Also note the elementary fact that an integer is odd iff its square is odd. $\quad \quad \quad \Box$

Now, if $c^2 = a^2 + b^2$ with both  $a$ an $b$ odd, then $c^2 = 1 +  1 = 2 (\text{ mod } 4)$, a contradiction, since the only squares modulo $4$ are $0$ and $1$. $\quad \quad \quad \Box$

Comment: Do you think this is different from the proof the OP mentions he already knows? Or that this proof is direct?